# Itegration of two programs in python

Tags: python

When click on run in the program I want:

1. my camera to initialize
2. take a picture of the object in front of it
3. detect the edges in that picture and save that picture
4. compare the current picture with an already existing picture I have in the database
5. calculate the difference in percentage between two pictures

Here is my code for the first 3 steps:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


camera_port = 0
ramp_frames = 30
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)
def get_image():
 retval, im = cap.read()
 return im

for i in xrange(ramp_frames):
 temp = get_image()
print("Taking image...")
# Take the actual image we want to keep
camera_capture = get_image()
file = "/Users/Me/Documents/python programs/New/test_image7.jpg"
# A nice feature of the imwrite method is that it will automatically choose the
# correct format based on the file extension you provide. Convenient!
cv2.imwrite(file, camera_capture)

# You'll want to release the camera, otherwise you won't be able to create a new
# capture object until your script exits
del(cap)

img1=cv2.imread('/Users/Me/Documents/python programs/New/test_image7.jpg',0)
#height, width, channels = img1.shape
#res = cv2.resize(img1,(width/2, height/2), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
#cv2.imshow('image',res)


edges = cv2.Canny(img1,100,200)
#plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img1,cmap = 'gray')
#plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(edges,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
#plt.save('/Users/Me/Documents/python programs/New/test_image2.jpg',img1)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and here is the code to get the difference between two edge images:

```
from itertools import izip
from PIL import Image

i1 = Image.open("pencil.png")
i2 = Image.open("eraser2.png")
assert i1.mode == i2.mode, "Different kinds of images."
assert i1.size == i2.size, "Different sizes."

pairs = izip(i1.getdata(), i2.getdata())
if len(i1.getbands()) == 1:
    # for gray-scale jpegs
    dif = sum(abs(p1-p2) for p1,p2 in pairs)
else:
    dif = sum(abs(c1-c2) for p1,p2 in pairs for c1,c2 in zip(p1,p2))

ncomponents = i1.size[0] * i1.size[1] * 3
print "Difference (percentage):", (dif / 255.0 * 100) / ncomponents
```

Now my question is ... How do I integrate these two programs, and how do I write this entire process in one program? Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you just have to embed everything into functions. It is usually discouraged to put everything flat into a file. Usually, for scripts, you'd prefer using the following structure:

`myscript.py`:

```
def main():
    # Your code here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And you can now call this script from your favorite command-line tool with `python myscript.py`. You could also use argparse to add some positional arguments. The structure also allows you to write unit tests. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) for more details.

Now, you could format your code as such:

```
from itertools import izip

import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

def take_and_save_picture(im_save):
  """Take a picture and save it

  Args:
    im_save: filepath where the image should be stored
  """
  camera_port = 0
  ramp_frames = 30
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)
  def get_image():
   retval, im = cap.read()
   return im

  for i in xrange(ramp_frames):
   temp = get_image()

  print("Taking image...")
  # Take the actual image we want to keep
  camera_capture = get_image()

  im_save_tmp = im_save + '.tmp'

  # A nice feature of the imwrite method is that it will automatically choose the
  # correct format based on the file extension you provide. Convenient!
  cv2.imwrite(im_save_tmp, camera_capture)

  # You'll want to release the camera, otherwise you won't be able to create a new
  # capture object until your script exits
  del(cap)

  img1 = cv2.imread(im_save_tmp, 0)

  edges = cv2.Canny(img1, 100, 200)
  cv2.imwrite(im_save, edges)
  cv2.waitKey(0)
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def compute_edges_diff(im1, im2):
  """Compute edges diff between to image files.

  Args:
    im1: filepath to the first image
    im2: filepath to the second image

  Returns:
    float: percentage of difference between images
  """

  i1 = Image.open(im1)
  i2 = Image.open(im2)
  assert i1.mode == i2.mode, "Different kinds of images."
  assert i1.size == i2.size, "Different sizes."

  pairs = izip(i1.getdata(), i2.getdata())
  if len(i1.getbands()) == 1:
      # for gray-scale jpegs
      dif = sum(abs(p1-p2) for p1,p2 in pairs)
  else:
      dif = sum(abs(c1-c2) for p1,p2 in pairs for c1,c2 in zip(p1,p2))

  ncomponents = i1.size[0] * i1.size[1] * 3
  diff = (dif / 255.0 * 100) / ncomponents
  return diff

def main():
  capture_img = 'path_to_the_future_captured_img.jpg'
  img_to_compare = 'the_image_used_for_scoring.jpg'
  take_and_save_picture(capture_img)
  diff = compute_edges_diff(im1, im2)
  print "Difference (percentage):", diff

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

As you can see, I moved some variables to function arguments, so that they can be called / set in one place. I reworked your function that takes a picture a bit so that the temporary jpeg file at the center has a different name. You can also compute differences between images directly from a function, which is nice.

Some final remarks:

- This allows you to unit test your functions. Use the built-in frame work and the `mock` library to replace calls to cv2.[functions]
- I was very tempted to move `get_image` out of the function, but I was lazy.

Comment: thank you very much for taking time to answer my question,.... this worked out perfectly ... i have a few more questions on this .. can i have your mail ID ? shall i mail it to u ?

Comment: i modified the code you gave and it worked ... now i need to know how to compare the current image with 10 other images in the database and give me the file with the least difference ...  i tried using this loop but its not working .. 


for no_file1 in range(10,100):
            template = cv2.imread('numbers1/{no_file}.jpg'.format(no_file=no_file1),0)

Comment: "not working" is very vague, but if you have 10 images, why not use range(10) instead of range(10, 100)?

Comment: ....  i need my code to compare the current image with 10 images in a particular folder ... eg : if there are 10 images in a file and one picture is captured now ... i need the system to compare the captured image with all 10 images in that particular folder and bring me the one with the least difference percentage .... how do i do this ?

Comment: Use a `for` loop iterating over the names of your 10 images and run `compute_edges_diff` for each one. Keep track of which image gives you the minimum or maximum score, and output this one.